# Is it possible to send files from FTP to Azure blob storage in timely basis?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-blob-storage

Basically in my scenario ,

I am storing all the files from different users in one ftp location and i want to send them to my azure blob storage account in a timely basis.

is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You want to upload the files to Azure Storage using FTP?

Comment: @peter Bons Yeah

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-logic-app-ftp-to-blob/

Answer (score 0):

> I am storing all the files from different users in one ftp location and i want to send them to my azure blob storage account in a timely basis.

As Peter Bons said, you can use Azure Logic Apps to transfer files from FTP into your Azure Blob Storage. You can follow these steps to use the FTP connector.

**create a connection to FTP**

[image]

**select a folder**

[image]

**add the action to get the contents of the file on the FTP server and create blob**

[image]

[image]

For detailed information, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp) that explained using the FTP connector to monitor, manage and create files on an FTP server.

Comment: Hi @Yaswanth, are you able to transfer files from your ftp server into your Azure Blob Storage now?